# Citrix connectivity issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, citrix, connectivity, windows-server-2003-r2

How is it possible to overcome connectivity issue from win server 2003 R2 to a Citrix based application hosted on a win server 2008 R2? Short summary of the problem is that while trying to connect from win server 2003 R2, to a certain URL (this goes for all browsers) hosted on win server 2008 R2 (Error code: sec_error_bad_signature).

Comment: What do you mean by "Citrix based application"? You have a published application on XenApp server? To what resource are you connecting? Is it web site or Citrix Web Interface or somthing else?

Comment: hi Mikhail, the issue here is that we are trying to access published application on XenApp server from 2003 win server. we are able to start the application, but when it starts opening there is a popup dialog saying:
Cannot connect to the Citrix XenApp server. There is no Citrix XenApp server configured on the specified address.
I've been told that the version Citrix Receiver is not supporting OS (Win Server 2003 R2), and as such the app can't be accessed.
The question is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Try to connect with Citrix QuickLaunch directly

Comment: If you have a single/double firewall this still may be a connectivity or routing error